# Back button on a question moves to tags page instead of list of questions for a specific tag on Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

Open the Tags page and select a specific tag(ex: Android)
View the list of questions and open a question for more details.
After answering the question press back button.
I expect to go back to question list but Stack Exchange Android app is taking me to list of Tags.

This is very inconvenient. Every time either I have to press back key once more or select the tag and again move to the place where I was previously.